# Como puedo modificar el rango de la variable aleatoria?

Tags: c, random

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int x;
    x=rand()%37 /// entrega numeros aleatorios entre 0 y 36
}
```

Mi consulta es, como puedo modificar o crear una variable en la que el rango de los numeros aleatorios sea de 1 a 36?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ya tienes de 0 a 36, y quieres pasar de 1 a 36, piensa que por una parte tienes que hacer el rango más pequeño, (restando 1 al módulo), pero empezando desde 1, es decir sumando 1 al total. Te queda esto:

```
x = (rand() % 36) + 1;
```